# tavis ci, jekyll, gh-pages: can't seem to push to gh-pages branch

Tags: git, github, jekyll, travis-ci, github-pages

I'm trying to use Travis CI to build my Jekyll site and push to my gh-pages branch on Github. It's not working, I probably don't know what I'm doing.

The error is:
`error: src refspec gh-pages does not match any.`
`error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/jshwlkr/jshwlkr.info.git'`

.travis.yml here: https://github.com/jshwlkr/jshwlkr.info/edit/master/.travis.yml

```
branches:
  only:
  - master
language: node_js
node_js:
- '6'
before_install:
- rvm install 2.2.3
- curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
before_script:
- gem install bundler
- bundle install
- mkdir _site
- git clone https://$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/jshwlkr/jshwlkr.info.git -v --branch gh-pages _site
- git status

after_success:
- cd _site
- git config user.email "email.me@jshwlkr.info"
- git config user.name "jshwlkr"
- git add --all
- git status
- git commit -a -m "Travis #$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
- git push --force origin gh-pages
- bundle exec rake webmention
```

last build here: https://travis-ci.org/jshwlkr/jshwlkr.info/builds/268142486

(I'm eventually going to either push to an additional server, or rsync. That's what those comments are.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travis checks out a shallow clone, so your local copy on the build VM does not know about the `gh-pages` branch, which exists [on GitHub](https://github.com/jshwlkr/jshwlkr.info/tree/gh-pages). Try fetching the branch with

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

before running `git push …`.

Alternatively, you might want to try the [GitHub Pages deployment provider](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages). There are a couple of reported bugs, such as https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7538 and https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7562, but you might find it suitable for your needs.

Comment: `fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense` is the reply

Comment: The deployment provider seems to work though! Thanks.